# Capture Datagridview cell kepress event

Tags: vb.net

Could any body kindly give me code example how to capture datagridview cell keypress event?
Datagridview_keypress does not help.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

As per Fco Navarro's answer, except that using `e.Control` does not always work because `e` is passed in to the `EditingControlShowing` event `ByVal` meaning any changes to the control (eg changing the `.Text` property) are NOT reflected in the DataGridView. If you need to do anything with the actual TextBox control in your event handler, you can use `DataGridView1.EditingControl` instead of `e.Control`.

```
Private WithEvents txtNumeric As New DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl

Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    txtNumeric = CType(DataGridView1.EditingControl, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
End Sub

Private Sub txtNumeric_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtNumeric.KeyPress
    txtNumeric.Text = txtNumeric.Text.ToUpper()
End Sub
```

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to ensure it's complete enough to stand on its own even if others are deleted.

Comment: Thanks @NathanTuggy. What specifically would you recommend? I think it does stand on it's own except for the reference to the other answer, which I'm including because sometime that answer will work, but other times it won't. I thought that would help people understand why I have contributed what appears to be a similar answer. Maybe that's not how SO works? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Basically, just add a bit more explanation for what the code was supposed to do before you added your tweaks.

Comment: This answer works great.  It allows me to make a column not editable, but without having to make it `ReadOnly`.  That way I am able to copy/paste the contents.

Comment: How can I use this but for only a specific column within a DGV?

Comment: Sorry @DevDave it's been a while since I wrote this answer - can you not test for the column name or index in DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing before setting txtNumeric to the current control? If I recall correctly, the sender object parameter should be the DataGridView itself, in which case you should be able to use the CurrentCell property to get the name or index to test against.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private WithEvents txtNumeric As New DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl

Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    txtNumeric = CType(e.Control, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
End Sub

Private Sub txtNumeric_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtNumeric.KeyDown
    If (e.KeyData >= Keys.A And e.KeyData <= Keys.Z) Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the KeyUp event instead of KeyPress. The trick is to attach the handler event to the ActiveControl property of form when the cell has the active state.

```
Private Sub grid_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles grid.CellBeginEdit
    AddHandler Me.ActiveControl.KeyUp, AddressOf Cell_KeyUp
End Sub

Private Sub Cell_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine(sender.Text) 'content of cell
End Sub
```

If you want to use also RemoveHandler method, you can add a global variable to the class (using this variable instead of Me.ActiveControl) and call RemoveHandler for example into the CellEndEdit event of DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing

    If Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 And Not e.Control Is Nothing Then
        Dim tb As TextBox = CType(e.Control, TextBox)
        AddHandler tb.KeyDown, AddressOf TextBox_KeyDown
        AddHandler tb.KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_KeyPress
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
    If  e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
        flag = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    e.Handled = flag
    flag = False
End Sub
```

Extracted from [here](http://www.coderewind.com/article/handling-keypress-and-keydown-events-for-datagridview/).

Answer (score 0):

if your using your gridview in asp.net (Website) its not possible. there is no keypress Event.
its possible indeed but you have to use JavaScript to make a postback on every keychanged (Client side). but this is not a nice programming style and should not be used (you are getting rly many postbacks which are slowing down the complete System).

if your using Windows forms: have a look at the answer from sysdragon.

hope this helps a bit.

best regards, noone

Answer (score 0):

the following code work perfectly:

```
Private WithEvents txtmontant As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl
Private Sub DGdivers_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DGdivers.EditingControlShowing
    If DGdivers.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        Dim txtmontant = CType(e.Control, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
        AddHandler txtmontant.KeyPress, AddressOf txtmontant_keypress
    Else
        RemoveHandler txtmontant.KeyPress, AddressOf txtmontant_keypress
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtmontant_keypress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtmontant.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = vbCr Then
        DGdivers.Rows.Add()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If e.KeyChar = vbBack Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If InStr("0123456789.,", e.KeyChar) = 0 Then
        e.KeyChar = ""
    End If
End Sub
```